# Dictionary copy from a dictionary class if dictionary available

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just want to copy a dictionary if available in dictionary class

testfolder/dict.py

```
    one={
    "one1":"one1Data",
    "one2":"one2Data",
    "one2":"one3Data"}

    two={
    "two1":"two1Data",
    "two2":"two2Data",
    "two2":"two3Data"}
```

test.py

```
   import testfolder.dict as dictRef

   print dictRef.two # it prints the dictionary)
```

But what i want to do is copy dictionary if available available in dictRef

```
    a='two' 
    if hasattr(dictRef, a): # this will not work but searching some alternate way to do..
    c = dictRef.a # Jus trying to achieve this
    print c # should print dictRef.two
```

Comment: Some confusion may be the result of 'dict' being a module, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
c = getattr(dictRef, 'two')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try:

```
if dictRef.has_key(key):
```

I think this is what you are looking for!